# xcodebuild archive with apollo dependency results in: "no such module 'SQLiteObjC'"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite, apollo

I am developing a iOS app which consists of multiple projects imported as frameworks.
These other projects are also supposed to be exported as an xcframework.

I am relying on a couple of dependencies using the swift package manager.

The specific one I have problems with is **Apollo**.
When building my app 'project' to my phone there is no problem.
But when trying to run the following command from my terminal:

```
xcodebuild archive \
-workspace Workspace.xcworkspace \
-scheme Framework \
-configuration Release \
-archivePath XCFrameworks/Framwork.xcarchive \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
ENABLE_BITCODE=YES \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

It tells me that **ARCHIVE FAILED**

With the following error:

```
/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<AppNameWithNonSenseLetters>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Framework/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SQLite.swift.build/Release-iphoneos/SQLite.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SQLite.swiftinterface:7:8: error: no such module 'SQLiteObjc'
import SQLiteObjc
       ^
```

followed by:

```
/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<AppNameWithNonSenseLetters>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Framework/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SQLite.swift.build/Release-iphoneos/SQLite.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SQLite.private.swiftinterface:1:1: error: failed to verify module interface of 'SQLite' due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
// swift-interface-format-version: 1.0
^
```

I am not importing SQLiteObjC anywhere myself. As I understand it, Apollo is depending on it.

How do I fix this?

I am using Xcode Version 15.2 and Apollo version 0.53.0